# Usage and implications of using "enableMultiInstanceInvalidation" in Room database

Tags: android, android-room

What are caveats of using enableMultiInstanceInvalidation. What all checks i should make when using this construct. Can i update my database builder if database is already created in the storage.

Answer (score 0):

MultiInstanceInvalidationClient is a non trivial amount of code and work that needs to happen when typically a DB is for a simple app/process.

https://androidx.tech/artifacts/room/room-runtime/2.1.0-alpha05-source/androidx/room/MultiInstanceInvalidationClient.java.html